# Model name when table name has underscore

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table `activity_logs`
What should I give the model name and model file name?

I have created the model file as activityLog.php and model class name as ActivityLog

But I couldn't retrieve the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cake php table names are plural and model names are singular. Table names with underscore are converted into camel case for naming models.

For example user_levels table will have model named as UserLevel:

UserLevel => user_levels

Even if you didn't create a model, Cake will let you use it and make one up on the fly for you, if you follow table names by above naming conventions.

If Cake "ignores" your model, it means it's making up another model on the fly, because you're not using the right name for the model you actually want

Looking at the generated SQL queries in debug = 2 helps

Answer (score 2):

For cakephp 2.0 and above, the naming convention are as follows:

Tables:

> Table names corresponding to CakePHP models are plural and underscored.

Join tables:

> Join tables, used in hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) relationships between
>   models should be named after the model tables they will join in
>   alphabetical order (apples_zebras rather than zebras_apples).

Controllers:

> Controller classnames are plural, CamelCased, and end in Controller.
>   PeopleController and LatestArticlesController are both examples of
>   conventional controller names.

Models:

> Model classnames are singular and CamelCased. Person, BigPerson, and ReallyBigPerson are all examples of conventional model names.

Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

For naming convention in lower version you can refer this blog: http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/08/complete-cakephp-naming-conventions/